# "Cross-Select" in Dojo?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, dojo

Example:
Having 2 dojo Select-Boxes.
In the first one you have to select a country, in the second one you have to select a city.
You can only select cities that are in the country you have selected.

How can this be done with dojo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described here : http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/form/FilteringSelect#codependent-filteringselect-combobox-widgets

Answer (score 1):

Generally its done by filtering the cities depending on the country selection. When someone selects his country, it will fire ajax to populate only cities in that country. To get the country and city listing you would use db queries in the server. It's a general overview which might give you some idea what is done actually.